# Pbi horizontal visual table

Tags: powerbi, dax, visualization, powerbi-desktop

I had a matrix visual created in my pbi report having regions in columns field

State in rows field and population in values field

Population is a calculated column made by using a formula

I need to create a table in an horizontal format showing max population per region with their respective State name ,i.e.,  the table should hold two rows one showing population data and another showing their respective State name as per the regions, indirectly regions are available in the column,

How can this be possible?

Unable to solve this situation

Comment: CN anyone solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You could make a rank state measure like so, which would rank each state per region.

```
Rank State = 
 
IF (
    ISINSCOPE('States'[State] ),
    RANKX (
        CALCULATETABLE (
            VALUES ('States'[State] ),
            ALLSELECTED ('States'[State] )
        ),
        [Population 2022]--this is my sum of population measure for that year. You may need to put a sum or other measure here.
    )
)
```

Then in your table, put a visual filter of when Rank State = 1

[image]